# how to get count of each element present in IN operator?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select trim(man_date_created) createddate,count(*) recordcount
from man 
where man_status IN ('received','acknowledge')
```

i want count of each like count of Accepted ,count of submitted. how can i extract it??

Comment: Why Java-tag? Take a look at GROUP BY in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select trim(man_date_created) createddate,
       count(*) recordcount,
       count(case when man_status = 'ACCEPTED' then 1 end) as accepted,
       count(case when man_status = 'SUBMITTED' then 1 end) as submitted,
       count(case when man_status = 'CREATED' then 1 end) as created,
       count(case when man_status = 'REJECTED' then 1 end) as rejected
from man 
where man_status IN ('ACCEPTED','SUBMITTED','CREATED','REJECTED')
group by man_date_created
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply do a `GROUP BY`. (With the `trim` part in a derived table, to be ANSI SQL compliant.)

```
select createddate, man_status, count(*)
from
(
    select trim(man_date_created) createddate, man_status 
    from man 
    where man_status IN ('ACCEPTED','SUBMITTED','CREATED','REJECTED')
)
group by createddate, man_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want counts even when they are zero, then use `left join` instead of `in`:

```
select s.status, count(man.man_status) as recordcount
from (select 'ACCCEPTED' as status from dual union all
      select 'SUBMITTED' as status from dual union all
      select 'CREATED' as status from dual union all
      select 'REJECTED' as status from dual union all
     ) s left join
     man 
     on man.man_status = s.status
group by s.status;
```

Include the date as well complicates the query.